I cannot get opencv's tiff compression to work
in opencv 4.10, we exposed all the compression parameters from libtiff:
cv::Mat1f image;
std::vector<int> compression_params = {
  cv::IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION, cv::IMWRITE_TIFF_COMPRESSION_LZMA
};
cv::imwrite(
    out_dir / str(boost::format{"%08d.tif"} % timestamp), 
    image,
    compression_params
);

the resulting file:
01160780.tif: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=11, height=76, bps=32, compression=none, PhotometricIntepretation=BlackIsZero, width=228

there is no compression at all.
But I can actually get PIL to compress it.
I also directly tried the libtiff in c++, which works fine too:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tiffio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void generateRandomMatrix(float* matrix, int width, int height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = static_cast<float>(rand()) / RAND_MAX; // Random float between 0.0 and 1.0
    }
}

void generateGradientMatrix(float* matrix, int width, int height) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            matrix[y * width + x] = static_cast<float>(x) / (width - 1); // Gradient from 0.0 to 1.0
        }
    }
}

void saveTiff(
    const std::string& filename,
    const std::vector<float>& floatMatrix,
    const int width,
    const int height,
    const int compression
) {
    TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(filename.c_str(), "w");
    if (!tif) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open TIFF file for writing: " << filename << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set TIFF file parameters for 32-bit floating point
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 32);       // 32 bits per sample
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);      // 1 sample per pixel
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISBLACK); // grayscale

    // Set the data type to floating point
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_SAMPLEFORMAT, SAMPLEFORMAT_IEEEFP);

    // Set compression type
    TIFFSetField(tif, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, compression);

    // Write the image data
    for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
        TIFFWriteScanline(
            tif,
            const_cast<float*>(floatMatrix.data() + row * width),
            row,
            0
        );
    }

    // Close TIFF file
    TIFFClose(tif);
}

int main() {
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0))); // Seed for random number generation

    const int width = 256;
    const int height = 256;
    const int numPixels = width * height;

    // Allocate memory for the float matrix
    std::vector<float> floatMatrix(numPixels);
    generateGradientMatrix(floatMatrix.data(), width, height);

    // Save TIFF with no compression
    saveTiff("gradient_float32_no_compression.tif", floatMatrix, width, height, COMPRESSION_NONE);

    // Save TIFF with LZMA compression
    saveTiff("gradient_float32_lzma.tif", floatMatrix, width, height, COMPRESSION_LZMA);


    std::cout << "TIFF image saved successfully!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


here we can see the compressing: unknown 0xffff886d
file gradient_float32_lzma.tif 
gradient_float32_lzma.tif: TIFF image data, little-endian, direntries=11, height=256, bps=32, compression=(unknown 0xffff886d), PhotometricIntepretation=BlackIsZero, orientation=upper-left, width=256

any idea, what might go wrong here?

The documentation says "Note, for images whose depth is CV_32F, only libtiff's SGILOG compression scheme is used." and Mat1f is single channel 32bit floating point...

that is not correct I actually can directly use libtiff to save the float32 matrix to tiff with lzma

That's all nice, but you're not using it directly, it's OpenCV calling it and that imposes some limitations.

Although it does seem to apply only for 3 channel images, otherwise it just disables compression completely.

@Wang that is not correct I actually can directly use libtiff -- LibTiff is only as good as the library and/or programs that utilizes it.  There are many programs, even ones that I've created, that do not support all of libtiff's compression algorithms, but do use libtiff internally.

so for some reason opencv guys artificially imposed this limitation:
            case CV_32F:
            {
                bitsPerChannel = 32;
                page_compression = COMPRESSION_NONE;
                sample_format = SAMPLEFORMAT_IEEEFP;
                break;
            }
            case CV_64F:
            {
                bitsPerChannel = 64;
                page_compression = COMPRESSION_NONE;
                sample_format = SAMPLEFORMAT_IEEEFP;
                break;
            }

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/79faf857d988bcbfc993f0a17cd38835d9d243d9/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_tiff.cpp#L1287
will report to there, to see why they think this is good idea

it's a "good idea" because someone had limited time to implement stuff, and that's where they stopped. if you want a feature, you're welcome to submit a pull request. or you can hope that someone eventually sees the issue and tries to work on it. chances are, someone without the required expertise will try it, and will either make it worse or give up. you'd best give this a try yourself. you know what you need out of it.
